# Disable Caps Lock when holding Shift on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, capslock, shift

On Windows devices, if Caps Lock is on and you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>,
Caps Lock is disabled (toggled off) until you let go.

For example, on Windows you could turn caps lock on to write this:

> LOREM ipsum DOLOR

and just hold Shift to go back to lowercase to write "ipsum".

However, on macOS you would have to disable Caps Lock to return to lowercase. Shift does nothing (apart from switching numbers to symbols).

Is there any way to get the *Windows-style* functionality on macOS?

---

[Apologies if this question's been asked before;
I've searched about and found no relevant posts.]

Comment: Did some digging - It looks like any options that do exist mess up other functions of the Keyboard (Ex. the symbols on the top row). It's been talked about for years but no one's found good functionality, from what I can gather

Comment: I really miss this on Mac...

Comment: Oh, what I really wanted is this: In Windows you can configure it so that every time you release Shift, you write in lowercase, disabling Capslock. This is awesome, cause it avoids the frequent mistake of pressing capslock to turn back to lower cases while it was already in lowercases - thus resulting in uppercases.... Not sure if I should open a  new question, but would this be possible in macOS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Mac (very familiar with Windows) and I totally agree that the option to "unlock" CAPS LOCK with the SHIFT key is such an excellent option. I believe this would always be the first thing I do when getting a new Windows machine on which it's not set up like this by default.
I'm also, even 4 years or so after your post, desperately looking for a solution on MacOS.
By any chance, have you found one, or "but you still haven't found what you're looking for", as U2 said :-)
Should I open a dedicated topic for that?
Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1224919)